# Hibernate Program Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Tags: java, hibernate

Below is the Hibernate program I am Testing and getting the error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment). 
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:129)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1290)
at test.Client.main(Client.java:31)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1018)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:501)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:437)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:954)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:639)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
... 5 more
```

Below is the Bean UserDetails.java class

```
package beans;



public class UserDetails {


private int userId;
private String userName;
private String userAddress;
private String userEmail;
private int userPhoneNo;
private String userPassword;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public String getUserPassword() {
    return userPassword;
}
public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getUserAddress() {
    return userAddress;
}
public void setUserAddress(String userAddress) {
    this.userAddress = userAddress;
}
public String getUserEmail() {
    return userEmail;
}
public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
public int getUserPhoneNo() {
    return userPhoneNo;
}
public void setUserPhoneNo(int userPhoneNo) {
    this.userPhoneNo = userPhoneNo;
}


}
```

Below is the mapping UserDetails.hbm.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="beans.UserDetails" table="User">
<id name="userId" column="UID" />

<property name="userName"></property>
<property name="userAddress"></property>
<property name="userEmail"></property> 
<property name="userPhoneNo"></property>
<property name="userPassword"></property>

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Below is the hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL</property>
<property name="hibernate.conection.username">system</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">system</property>
<property name="hibernate.conection.pool-size">1</property>

<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="show-sql">true</property>

<mapping resource="resources/UserDetails.hbm.xml"/>


</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below is the Test class Client.java

```
package test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import beans.UserDetails;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserDetails ud=new UserDetails();
    ud.setUserId(100);
    ud.setUserName("ABC");
    ud.setUserAddress("ABCDEF");
    ud.setUserEmail("ABC@gmail.com");
    ud.setUserPassword("12345");
    ud.setUserPhoneNo(98765);

    Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");

    //System.out.println("Configure complete");

    SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session s=sf.openSession();

    s.save(ud);

    s.beginTransaction().commit();

    sf.close();



}

}
```

I have checked with a simple JDBC program with the same details and the program is running successfully.

Request you to let me know the issue with the Hibernate program.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `invalid username/password; logon denied` - I would start there.

Comment: Which part of *"SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"* is confusing you?

Comment: I am using the same login ID and Password to connect to the database manually as well as simple JDBC program. Also in the first part of the error msg 
'Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection'-- The error is occurring at the line number 31 of the Client.java file where I am trying to commit the session.